# Populate a ComboBox with the Result of a Text Box

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in my Access database called:

- formAcademyRegister

Inside this form I have a combo box called:

- EmployeeCode

This combo box retrieves its data from a table called:

- Employees

The primary key on this field is EmployeeID

To make it easier for the user I created a form called formsEmployeeSearch. In this form use some text fields to make it easier to search for the employee using a first name or last name, returing the values to a list box on this form. This list box has three fields:

1. EmployeeID
2. FirstName
3. LastName

All these fields are also populated using the Employees table so there won't be any data type issues.

Below the list box on the search form I have a button called

- butUpdateEmployeeID

When the button is clicked, I want the following to happen:

1. The EmployeeCode combo box in the formAcademyRegister be updated with the employeeID as selected in the list in the formsEmployeeSearch form
2. The formsEmployeeSearch to be closed

I am comfortable with the process of closing the form, I am however struggling with the code to populate that combo box with the value selected in the list box.

I tried the following:

```
Me.Form!formAcademyRegister!EmployeeCode = Me!lstEmpSearchResult.Value
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below.

```
Forms.formAcademyRegister.EmployeeCode.Value = lstEmpSearchResult.Value
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSavePrompt
```

A couple of notes.

1. The keyword `Me` is not required when the code is behind the form itself, but in some situations it makes the code more readable.
2. The `.Value` property is default property (where applicable) thus can be omitted. It's best practice to keep it for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Me.Form is reference to current Form (where code is).
Forms is collection. Assignement to collection item "Collection(ItemNameOrItemIndex)

```
Forms("formAcademyRegister").cmbEmployeeCode.Value = Me.lstEmpSearchResult
```